# Not to destroy EJB instance if exception throws

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

Is there anyway to not destroy the ejb instance if uncought exception throws to container?
If ejb throws any exception to container then container will remove its instance from pool so my question is.Is there anyway/configuration not to destroy/remove its(instance) from pool even with exception throws from ejb?

Answer (score 2):

No, if an EJB throws a *system exception* rather than a declared *application exception*, then there is no standard way to prevent the instance from being removed.  Your only option in that case is to ensure that a checked/application exception is thrown instead.  For example, wrap the method body in a try/catch for the system exception, ensure the instance state is still valid (which is the reason system exceptions normally cause the instance to be discarded), and then wrap/rethrow as a checked/application exception.